# Trigger that sends email in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to send email in a trigger. I am using `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` for that. I have problem how to setup permissions properly.

I do not want to add `DatabaseMailUserRole` of `msdb` to the user of the database which has access to the data.

Therefore, I have created another user `mailer` who has `DatabaseMailUserRole`.

The trigger definition is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger
    ON MyTable
    WITH EXECUTE AS 'mailer'
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail ...
END
```

I am getting the following error:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

(When I remove the `WITH EXECUTE AS 'mailer'` and add `DatabaseMailUserRole` to the user who is accessing the database, it works correctly.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql server execute as permission errors in trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709335/sql-server-execute-as-permission-errors-in-trigger)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend *not* to do any heavy lifting and/or time consuming tasks (like sending an e-mail) in a trigger.

The trigger gets executed in the context of the transaction that caused it to fire - and that transaction will have to wait until the trigger and all its operations are done. This is a sure fire way to kill off any performance in your system.

What I'd rather recommend is this:

- inside your trigger, just make a "note" into a table that something needs to be done (like sending an e-mail; store all the relevant info that you need into that table) - and then that's all the trigger does
- create a separate, stand-alone task (e.g. a scheduled job, run by the SQL Server Agent) that checks that "command" table periodically, and then actually does the action needed - like sending the e-mail, updating a large number of rows, exporting data - whatever it might be

With such a setup, you make sure your triggers stay *lean and nimble* and don't cause more slowdown on your system than absolutely necessary.

Comment: Is sending an email heavy lifting operation? I thought that email is just queued not directly sent.

I am sending email only in case of an critical error detected there.

Comment: @TN: sending an e-mail *can* take a long time, if the SMTP transmission runs into problems - there are some timeouts in play, and adding 30 or 60 seconds to your transaction is *not* a good idea!

Comment: You think that `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` waits until SMTP transmission completes? I thought that email is just queued to be sent and `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` is not waiting until the email is sent.